# memory limit not upgrade

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, xampp, macbook, memory-limit

memory_limit=4G
php_value memory_limit 4G

I tried every way but no result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> **Please try to add this to your command and run**

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:install ..............
```

> **Also, you can check the memory limit using the below command**

```
php -i | grep "memory_limit"
```

Answer (score 0):

> Increase memory LIMIT in phpinfo URL, Please see the screenshot

[image]

> Change the master value to 4048M which is given in the screenshot. Then try to run with this command memory_limit=4G